# MapInfo 12.5 or 16 writing scripts

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

Fairly new to MapInfo both versions. I am a efficient user of ArcGIS, but my query being I was reading up on MapBasic but all the examples for these scripts are for running within MapInfo. Is there any way you can write script (stand alone) outside of MapInfo to make it do something?

I would like some suggestions on what other software can control MapInfo. I am used to writing python scripts outside of ESRI ArcGIS desktop and being able to run the mxds without even opening up the maps. So similarly I wanted to know what can be done for MapInfo?

Comment: There is talk of future versions of MapInfo moving away from MapBasic and using Python. No idea on timescales or the extent of the integration but apparently it's on the cards.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, if you run MapInfo from the command line with the `-server` parameter then MapInfo will run in the background with no splash-screen and no application window. You can then run your MBX on this instance of MapInfo which will continue to run in the background. Obviously you will probably want to close the MapInfo instance programatically once you've finished processing as there will be no application window to close.

For more info and an example you can have a look [here](http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CqveCAC&popup=false&lang=en_US).